# How do you set up a Report Server instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to set up Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services. I open the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, and it asks for a Server name. Thing is, I don't know the server name, because as far as I know haven't set a report server up yet. So, how do you set one up for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2? There seems to be plenty of documentation out there how to configure one, but not how to install a new instance.

Comment: The servername is the name to reference to access your SSRS report instance IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Server name is the name of the database server. You first have to install SQL server on the server you want to use and then install Reporting Services. When installing SSRS you specify the name of the SQL Server.

It does not have to be on the same machine of course.