# How do you set up a MS SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services Report Server instance?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a running MS SQL Server 2017 (Enterprise edition), but it seems, that there is no MS SQL Server Reporting Services Report Server Instance.

I've read [How do you set up a Report Server instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875585/how-do-you-set-up-a-report-server-instance), but that doesn't address my issue. See the attached image. I know Server Name, but there is no instance to select. If I click the Find button, I get an error message saying "Unable to connect to Report Server XXXX".

I'm not sure, whether MS SQL Server Reporting Services are correctly installed (a company co-worker gave me this server on Azure for further use). If I launch "MS SQL Server Installation Center" and select "Install SQL Server Reporting Services", I'm redirected to download an installation program "SQLServerReportingServices", but that cannot be run on a domain controller, which this server happens to be (because it is intended for development use).

Pointers to solution appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to guess it's not installed - is there a service called "SQL Server Reporting Services" in your services applet? and as you've found, you can't install it on a domain controller. It's really quite simple to run up VM's in Azure, even a VM with SSRS pre-installed. I suggest you do that.

Comment: You're right. There wasn't such service, and yes, I found out, that you can't install on a domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing MS SQL Server 2016 on the same virtual machine, because the SSRS 2016 can be installed and run on a domain controller. This satisfies the requirements for this simple test bed (neither connected to any company domain nor going to contain any valuable data).